# how to store multiple form data and send them to next view?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I am having three different tab window where I have seperate form in each page. I need to store my first form content and post them to controller from second content. Similarly on third page after filling those content I need to insert them on the table in my database.
This is my controller page.

```
<?php
class Admin_employee extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('employee_model');
    $this->load->model('add_service_model');
        $this->load->model('designation_model');

        if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }
     public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('tax_details');
        //all the posts sent by the view
        $manufacture_id = $this->input->post('category');        
        $search_string = $this->input->post('search_string');        
        $order = $this->input->post('order'); 
        $order_type = $this->input->post('order_type'); 

        //pagination settings
        $config['per_page'] = 999999;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/employee';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';


        //math to get the initial record to be select in the database
        $limit_end = ($page * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
        if ($limit_end < 0){
            $limit_end = 0;
        } 



    }//index


    public function form1()
    {

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'id');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_first_name', 'emp_first_name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_last_name', 'emp_last_name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_email_id', 'emp_email_id');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_emergency_contact', 'emp_emergency_contact');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'category');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_id_card', 'emp_id_card');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_date_of_hire', 'emp_date_of_hire');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_date_of_termination', 'emp_date_of_termination');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_date_of_rehire', 'emp_date_of_rehire');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_reference_num', 'emp_reference_num');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_service_limitation', 'emp_service_limitation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_active', 'emp_active');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('chair_renter', 'chair_renter');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

            //if the form has passed through the validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data_to_store = array(
                     'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                    'emp_first_name' => $this->input->post('emp_first_name'),
                    'emp_last_name' => $this->input->post('emp_last_name'),
                    'emp_email_id' => $this->input->post('emp_email_id'),
                    'emp_emergency_contact' => $this->input->post('emp_emergency_contact'),          
                    'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                    'emp_id_card' => $this->input->post('emp_id_card'),
                    'emp_time_in' => $this->input->post('emp_time_in'),
                    'emp_time_out' => $this->input->post('emp_time_out'),
                    'emp_date_of_hire' => $this->input->post('emp_date_of_hire'),
                    'emp_date_of_termination' => $this->input->post('emp_date_of_termination'),
                    'emp_date_of_rehire' => $this->input->post('emp_date_of_rehire'),
                    'emp_reference_num' => $this->input->post('emp_reference_num'),
                    'emp_service_limitation' => $this->input->post('emp_service_limitation'),
                    'chair_renter' => $this->input->post('chair_renter'),

                );



        }


         if($this->employee_model->store_employee($data_to_store)){
                    $data['flash_message'] = TRUE; 
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');
                }else{
                    $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 



            }

        }
        $data['designation'] = $this->designation_model->get_designation();
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/employee/add';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
    } 
    public function form2()
    {
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'id');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_active', 'emp_active');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('chair_renter', 'chair_renter');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

            //if the form has passed through the validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data_to_store = array(
                     'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                         'emp_active' => $this->input->post('emp_active'),
                'chair_renter' => $this->input->post('chair_renter'),

                );



        }


         if($this->employee_model->store_employee($data_to_store)){
                    $data['flash_message'] = TRUE; 
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');
                }else{
                    $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 



            }

        }

    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/employee/service_limitations';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    } 

}
```

Here I have 2 function. `form1` and `form2`. when I save my data in second form I need to insert the values from first form and second form. How to do it? Can someone help me code?

Comment: Store all the posted data in session one by one and finally add them to db at the last controller once you have all the data.

Comment: how to use them. please give me some code snippet@Arjun

Comment: Instead of storing data into DB in form1, store it into session. Than in form2 check if there are some data in session variables and store them to DB in that step before or after storing form2 data. It is impossible tell more because we don't know client side requirements (what should happen, when, what need to trigger for that etc). You have to see how to distinct stored session data to have fine identifier related to relation `form1<->form2`.

Comment: I will try this. Can you give me some code snippet or fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

**Check this workflow**

PHP Controller Part :

```
    public function __construct(){......  }

    public function index()
    {... }//index


    public function form1()
    {

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'id');

           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_first_name', 'emp_first_name','required');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_last_name', 'emp_last_name','required');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_email_id', 'emp_email_id');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_emergency_contact', 'emp_emergency_contact');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'category');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_id_card', 'emp_id_card');

           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_date_of_hire', 'emp_date_of_hire');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_date_of_termination', 'emp_date_of_termination');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_date_of_rehire', 'emp_date_of_rehire');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_reference_num', 'emp_reference_num');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_service_limitation', 'emp_service_limitation');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_active', 'emp_active');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('chair_renter', 'chair_renter');
           $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

            //if the form has passed through the validation
           if ($this->form_validation->run())
           {
            $data_to_store = array(
               'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
               'emp_first_name' => $this->input->post('emp_first_name'),
               'emp_last_name' => $this->input->post('emp_last_name'),
               'emp_email_id' => $this->input->post('emp_email_id'),
               'emp_emergency_contact' => $this->input->post('emp_emergency_contact'),          
               'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
               'emp_id_card' => $this->input->post('emp_id_card'),
               'emp_time_in' => $this->input->post('emp_time_in'),
               'emp_time_out' => $this->input->post('emp_time_out'),
               'emp_date_of_hire' => $this->input->post('emp_date_of_hire'),
               'emp_date_of_termination' => $this->input->post('emp_date_of_termination'),
               'emp_date_of_rehire' => $this->input->post('emp_date_of_rehire'),
               'emp_reference_num' => $this->input->post('emp_reference_num'),
               'emp_service_limitation' => $this->input->post('emp_service_limitation'),
               'chair_renter' => $this->input->post('chair_renter'),

               );

}


// if($this->employee_model->store_employee($data_to_store)){
//     $data['flash_message'] = TRUE; 
//     $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');
// }else{
//     $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
// }

}

//save this data to session 
$this->session->set_userdata('form1data', $data_to_store);
//redirect to next form

$data['designation'] = $this->designation_model->get_designation();
$data['main_content'] = 'admin/employee/add';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
} 

public function form2()
{
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'id');

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_active', 'emp_active');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('chair_renter', 'chair_renter');
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

            //if the form has passed through the validation
       if ($this->form_validation->run())
       {
        $data_to_store = array(
           'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
           'emp_active' => $this->input->post('emp_active'),
           'chair_renter' => $this->input->post('chair_renter'),

           );

    }
}

    //save this data to session 
$this->session->set_userdata('form2data', $data_to_store);

//redirect to next form

}

//after all forms call this function
public function save_all_data_to_db() {
    $form1 = $this->session->userdata('form1data');
    $form2 = $this->session->userdata('form2data');

    //process and save everything to db
}
```

Front END:
When the user finishes first form and clicks next, post all the form data to controller.

Post to controller via javascript :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#somebutton').on('click', function() {
        $.post( "/form1", {
            "emp_first_name" : val,
            .
            .
            .
            .
        },function( data ) {
            //load next tab
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not have submit button in my first form Instead I need to switch over to next tab menu. How to do that? How to send my form data to controller page?

Comment: Is it only possible with Jquery? I do not have tab like <li> I am having buttons using <a>. How to check that click in my page? can you please guide me?